# Generate unique notification from a value in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm little stuck and would appreciate your help. I'm trying to generate a single notification contains value only from an object. In that case would be 3 different notifications.

That is my notification:

```
 dispatch(triggerNotification({
   type: 'error',
   msg: validation.errors,
   duration: 10
 }))
```

Where the "msg: validation.errors" is my object, which objects contains

```
error1: "Error1"
error2: "Error2"
error3: "Error3"
and so on
```

Here I return a new array with values only.

```
var arrayErrors = Object.values(varErrors)
["error1", "error2", "error3"]
```

Now I would like to generate three notifications - 1 contains "error1", 2 contains "error2"...

Thank you.

Comment: `validation.errors.error1` Do you mean?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Exactly. One notifaction with .error1, second with .error2, third with .error3 and so on.

Comment: now what the notification prints? the JSON format/stringified  of the whole object?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Yes, whole object.
react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {error1, error2, error3}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: This is unclear. What is your question?

Comment: Convert `validation.errors` to the Array with 3 different messages.

Comment: so in triggerNotification where you receive the whole object iterate over it with `map`. `msg.keys.map(key=>msg[key] .... )` and treat each as a single message. if you need more help post the complete snippet of where you create notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops) to iterate through the errors and trigger a notification for each one:

```js
for (let [key, msg] of Object.entries(validation.errors)) {
  dispatch(triggerNotification({
    type: 'error',
    msg,
    duration: 10
  }))
}
```